# Connecting to my remote mysql database from my C# apllication

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Ok so I am trying to connect to my database from my web host but the support people keep saying use "localhost" well in my C# program if I use "localhost" it connects to the mysql database on my local machine.

I was just wanting to know if there was something I could put under the "Server" parameter when connect to my database from my program to make it connect to my server and use "localhost" while under my server? Would I have to do something with DNS? and if so what do I add? It says "Name" and "Address" under my DNS record editor for my webhost.

This is my code 
**Requested by: JMK**  (password and uid censored out)

```
string connString = "Server=localhost.mydomain.com;Database=***;Uid=bender;password=***";
           MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
           MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";
            try
           {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
          MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(reader["username"].ToString());
            }
```

this is my code. I've tried "localhost.mydomain.com" but it just redirects it to my localhost machine. How would I obtain my domain's ip?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? You should just need to put the IP address of the MySQL server under the "server" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to "support people" server you need to specify it address. They want you to use localhost because probably app will be standing on the same machine where server runs, but you are developing on your local machine, so localhost is your PC itself. For more flexibility I'd use 2 config files (Release and Debug) to assign automatically to which machine connect (target machine name taken from target team or localhost which will point to your PC).

Answer (score 0):

They're saying localhost because the database is running on the same server as the web server.  When you say "connect to my database from my program to make it connect to my server" do you mean your own database server that's not on your dev PC?

If you're using .NET 4 you can actually run a transform on your web.config to change settings based on your target configuration.  That way you could have a Debug config that will be used when you're running it on your local machine, and a Release config that would be used when you Publish the project in Release mode.  To switch between then you just change the Build Configuration in visual studio.

HEre's a little more information on how it works:  http://www.shubho.net/2011/03/transformation-webconfig-aspnet-40.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use godaddy.com it offers you the option to have mysql database globally accessible and gives you the host name that you can use anywhere. Not all providers offer that option. 
You also should consider delays and unsecured data transfer that would take place when you do it over the Internet.

Comment: ya I use x10 hosting and I don't think I have that option.